# Can I read token balance changes from simulateTransaction result?

Tags: transactions

Is it possible to read token balances changes from simulateTransaction result?

```
const simulationResult = await connection.simulateTransaction(transaction, undefined, true);
```

How do existing wallets estimate balance changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a completely straightforward way. `simulateTransaction` will return an array of accounts under `value.accounts`, that is the state of accounts *post simulation*. If you know the state of accounts *pre simulation* you can compare the two.

Generally speaking:

1. You can directly compare `lamports` on pre / post to find SOL balance changes
2. You can compare the *parsed* data from those accounts owned by the token program to see balance changes

Here's a bit of code that provides snippets of usefulness without providing the full answer. You probably *also* want to filter on the size of the account not just owner to make sure it's actually a token account.

```
import { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, u64 } from '@solana/spl-token';

const tokenProgramString = TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID.toBase58();

const balances = accounts
  .filter(a => a.owner === tokenProgramString)
  .map(a => u64.fromBuffer(Buffer.from(a.data[0], 'base64').slice(64, 64 + 8)))
```

Comment: is there any documentation on what is stored inside a.data[0]?

Comment: The `data` field is a two-element array with data[0] being the base64 representation of the account data and data[1] being the string `base64` denoting the representation. It's documented here: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#results

Comment: This is interpreted different for different account types. For token accounts, you can find the binary layout here https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/48fbb5b7c49ea35848442bba470b89331dea2b2b/token/js/src/state/account.ts#L59

Comment: I went down this rabbit hole last year; If you’re going to try to trust simulation results a takeaway is that you need to make sure your RPC node is caught up. Especially, if you are talking to an RPC cluster. For example, the current node could be behind and give you incorrect results or it could be at the same slot number but on a fork that doesn’t include a transaction that changed the balance. Honestly, I’d recommend local simulation if possible.

Comment: Im trying to parse data using AccountLayout. AccountLayout.decode(Buffer.from(a.data[0], 'base64'))

But it doesn't work :(

Comment: Added a modified version of yamen code

Comment: Yamen, for SOL balance change Im not sure how to map to owner wallet. 

Those accounts have no indication of who they belong too.

      {
        "data":[
           "",
           "base64"
        ],
        "executable":false,
        "lamports":15324222,
        "owner":"11111111111111111111111111111111",
        "rentEpoch":329
     },
     {
        "data":[
           "",
           "base64"
        ],
        "executable":false,
        "lamports":576529689,
        "owner":"11111111111111111111111111111111",
        "rentEpoch":328
     },

Comment: The order of accounts returned is the same order as they are supplied in the underlying transaction, this is how your map them back.

Answer (score 2):

Was able to make it work with the following code.

```
import {
  AccountLayout,
  ACCOUNT_SIZE,
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
} from '@solana/spl-token';

const simulationResult = await connection.simulateTransaction(transaction, undefined, true);

const tokenProgramString = TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID.toBase58();

const balances = simulationResult.value.accounts
  .filter((a) => {
   const data = Buffer.from(a.data[0], 'base64');
   return a.owner === tokenProgramString && data.length === ACCOUNT_SIZE;
  }).map((a) => {
    const data = Buffer.from(a.data[0], 'base64');
    return AccountLayout.decode(data);
  });
```

Comment: annotating the code would improve the quality of this answer.  why does it work?